# Comparison of two classifiers based on precision/recall/F1 only?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, precision-recall

For two classifiers **h1** and **h2** I have the precision, recall and F1 score as a percentage (along with the original labeled data set that they were tested on). If I had access to which samples each classifier classified right/wrong, I would be able to do, for example,  McNemar's test to evaluate significance, but unfortunately I don't.

I would ideally like to be able to speak on the significance of the results obtained by **h2**, that is, whether **h2** is a significant improvement over **h1**. Am I unable to do that, or is there *something* I can say using only precision/recall/F1 and the labeled data set?

Comment: Do you have the quality values per class at least, or do you only have a global measure only?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It looks like I'll have to re-train the models and get proper output - Doesn't look like I can say much based on what I'd gathered previously.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is P/R/F1 scores for the two systems/classifiers there's no way of testing whether the difference between the two is statistically significant. For the McNemar's test, as you suggested, you would need the predictions of the two systems.

If you have other labeled data and the implementation of the two systems, you can test those on the data (shuffling and 5- or 10-fold cross-validating several times) so that you can perform a statistical test.

Comment: could you clarify what test could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have different options about how to compare different classifiers in the text domain. However, you will need quality levels per class or per document. You can check this paper about [Re-examining text categorisation methods](http://www.inf.ufes.br/~claudine/courses/ct08/artigos/yang_sigir99.pdf).